# Can i use ob_start to include an external php file that holds variables?

Tags: php

is this possible and if yes how would i go by this approach, i don't really get what is the purpose of ob_start since i have not used this function and i don't really know when to use this function.

i have already asked a similar question here but failed to get any answer, so i am hoping that with this more accurate question i could now get a better answer to this dilemma, i also understand that there other ways for me to do this via SVN but i would like to continue with the approach of including an external file.

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

the OB (output buffering) system only affects **OUTPUT**. it captures anything that would normally be sent to the remote browser and stores it in a memory buffer. As far as your average piece of PHP code is concerned, nothing has changed, except output has been temporarily trapped.

OB is handy in some cases, e.g. for whatever reason you might be producing output, but can't have it be sent out yet, e.g.

```
echo 'this will break the next line';
header("Location: otherpage.php");
```

Adding in output buffering would allow the header redirect to work:

```
ob_start();
echo 'this would have broken the next line, but output has been trapped';
header("Location: otherpage.php");
echo ob_get_clean(); // output actually occurs here
```

Comment: i did not know that, i had a hard time working with headers before because they have an echo before them, thank you for this bits of information, but regarding my original question, is it possible?

Comment: ob has nothing to do with including files.

Comment: but if i were to use file_get_contents and use ob to so that the content of the file is not printed out but instead treated as part of the file. i am making any sense?

Answer (score 1):

As another poster mentioned, ob_start doesn't have any effect on input to your program.

If you want to include a PHP file full of variables to an individual script, I recommend using require_once (http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).  This will evaluate the given PHP file in the current scope if and only if it hasn't been evaluated before.  I say to use the require_once function because include will not tell you if the file failed to load and the _once aspect of the structure ensures that you won't reload the file if multiple PHP files are accessed (which can be a headache).

If you're looking to bring variables from a file into EVERY php program that runs on your server, consider the php.ini directive auto_prepend_file (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).  This directive will load a file (much like include or require) for every request before evaluating your scripts.

If this isn't what you're looking for, can you clarify what you're looking for?

EDIT: Example from comments

```
$myStringArray = file('http://somewhere.com/file.txt');  //get the file contents as an array of lines

$myEvaluationString = ''; //set up a string which we will eventually evaluate

foreach ($myStringArray as $line) {

  $myEvaluationString = "$line\n"; //loop over each line and add it to our evaluation string

}

$myEvaluationString = rtrim($myEvaluationString); //clean off the trailing newline

eval($myEvaluationString); //evaluate the string
```

Comment: i am trying to include an external php file, the file is like http://www.somewhere.com/file.php to be included at http://www.here.com/index.php

Comment: Ah, that's not really possible unless the file is being served in raw text.  Somewhere.com isn't going to give you the code when you access file.php, it's going to give you the result of evaluating file.php.  If you have control over somewhere.com, you could rename the file so that mod_php will just ignore it and apache would serve it as text.  Maybe file_php.txt.  Then you could theoretically parse it by pulling it into a string in index.php via a curl request and running eval (http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) on the string.

Comment: thats a bit confusing in my part, care to explain it more? i tried using file_get_contents before but ended up displaying the contents of file.php instead of integrating it on index.php, though someone told me that i could use ob_start for this problem.

Comment: You have two files on two different servers.  In order to pull in variables from file.php on somewhere.com, you'd have to somehow have here.com access the raw contents of file.php and evaluate it in here.com's PHP scope.  The problem is, the server at somewhere.com is going to RUN (evalaute) file.php when you request the file, not deliver the file contents.  Your options are to either get somewhere.com to send you the raw file (my renaming suggestion), or simply upload file.php from somewhere.com to here.com and use include or require.

Comment: can you give me an example on sending it as raw file and retrieving it. sorry for the bother but this is my first time encountering this scenario. thank you

Comment: On somewhere.com, copy the file.php to another extension, perhaps file.txt.  Then, go to somewhere.com/file.php and somewhere.com/file.txt and compare the different output to your browser.

Comment: can you post an answer to this with example on curl and eval running the retrieve for file.txt since im sure file.txt will return everything inside it as string

Comment: Actually, just using file() might be simpler:

$myStringArray = file('http://somewhere.com/file.txt');  //get the file contents as an array of lines

$myEvaluationString = ''; //set up a string which we will eventually evaluate

foreach ($myStringArray as $line) {

  $myEvaluationString = "$line\n"; //loop over each line and add it to our evaluation string

}

$myEvaluationString = rtrim($myEvaluationString); //clean off the trailing newline

eval($myEvaluationString); //evaluate the string